# Set symbol on lines according to line features length

Tags: symbology, mapserver, mapfile

I need to display arrows alongside to line features. Lines represent water pipes. The issue I'm facing is that lines are a concatenation of numerous line features of various lengths. Therefore, symbols are attached to every line, whatever its length. This makes symbols either overlaying or touching eachother (as in example below).

[image: Water pipes with touching arrow symbols]

Inside my mapfile, I define the display rules of my symbols in the `STYLE` element:

```
    STYLE
        SYMBOL "wp_arrow"
        GAP -100
        COLOR 255 0 0
        OFFSET -5 -99
        SIZE 6
    END
```

I would like these rules to apply only to line features being more than 10 meters long (or x map units).

Comment: What about generating a column with the length of the lines and then using two classes depending on the length attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Using geotransform might help you in this case, something like:

```
STYLE
GEOMTRANSFORM "end"
COLOR 100 200 100
SYMBOL "arrow"
SIZE 7.0
ANGLE AUTO
END # STYLE
```

It'd be easier to just add a "pseudo-arrow" symbol like this:

```
SYMBOL
  NAME "V"
  TYPE truetype
  FONT "arial"
  CHARACTER "V"
END # SYMBOL
```

I received these solutions from a similar problem with line features, you can find the whole story here: [MapServer: Symbol (v-line) style that automatically follows line direction](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157472/mapserver-symbol-v-line-style-that-automatically-follows-line-direction)